# VB.Net issue with double data range while performing a linear regression

Tags: vb.net, linear-regression

I am performing linear regression using this data in VB.Net

`1411478155,71.9700012207031
1411478150,72.9700012207031
1411478145,73.9700012207031
1411478140,74.9700012207031
1411478135,76.9700012207031
1411478130,78.9700012207031
1411478125,80.9700012207031
1411478120,81.9700012207031
1411478115,82.9700012207031
1411478110,84.9700012207031
1411478105,85.9700012207031
1411478100,88.9700012207031`

The formula that I am using is this,

[image]

where x = UTC Seconds, y = Values

In the denominator, I am getting a zero value because both expressions in the denominator equal to a value of `2.8688695263517E+20`.

I defined my series as,

`Dim xs(12) As [Double]
Dim ys(12) As [Double]`

I am not sure if the square brackets matter.
For now, I am not able to get results due to zero denominator. What data type should I use?
I expect more rows of data in future.

Edit:
Given below is the sub

`

```
    Public Sub GetLinearRegressionParams(ByVal xs() As Double, ByVal ys() As Double, ByRef a As Double, ByRef b As Double)
    Dim sumX As Double = 0
    Dim sumY As Double = 0
    Dim sumXY As Double = 0
    Dim sumX2 As Double = 0
    Dim n As Integer
    n = 0 
    For index = 0 To xs.Length - 1
        If xs(index) = Nothing Then
        Else
            sumX = sumX + xs(index)
            sumY = sumY + ys(index)
            sumXY = sumXY + xs(index) * ys(index)
            sumX2 = sumX2 + xs(index) * xs(index)
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next

    a = (sumY * sumX2 - sumX * sumXY) / (n * sumX2 - sumX * sumX)
    b = (n * sumXY - sumX * sumY) / (n * sumX2 - sumX * sumX)

End Sub
```

`

Comment: *Double* can hold the values without any problem. How do you calculate the denominator?

Comment: You'll have to provide some code in order to help you. Likely the way you coded the formula is wrong.

Comment: `Denominator = (n * sumX2 - sumX * sumX)`

Comment: provide code please?

Comment: Please see the sub that calculates these values.(I couldn't show For loop starting on a new line.). I have some `Nothing` values in the array which I am ignoring.

Comment: Initialize your arrays with *0.0R* and check *If xs(index) = 0.0R Then*. Also change *n* with *CDbl(n)* in your calculations. I am not saying that this is the problem but it is the correct way. Your code is fine, the problem is in the arrays

Comment: You can ignore `If xs(index) = Nothing Then` because in this dataset I don't have `Nothing` values.

Comment: I used `CDbl(input)` to assign values to my array. I also defined `Dim n as Double`. This seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Be advised that `Nothing` in VB.Net is not the same thing as `null` in c#.  In VB, `Nothing` for value types means to use the default value for the type.  Confirm that you are not entering the True block of the `If xs(index) = Nothing` statement.  Also be aware that your arrays contain _13_ indices and not 12.  In VB.Net, when declaring an array, you specify the upper bound, not the count.  Your arrays are 13 in length but you only showed 12 data points.  Was that intentional?

Comment: I just tested the code you posted.  If I add a zero to any of the indices of the `xs` array, then the `If xs(index) = Nothing` test returns true.  I would just eliminate that test altogether.

Comment: The double data type probably has a precision of 15 where all numbers after first 15 numbers will be replaced by zero. This is true for Excel as well. The alternative might be to use `BigInteger`